# connect-roles: Define User Roles on Login and User.is function

Tags: node.js, express

I try to use connect-roles (https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/connect-roles) but I'm struggling with defining the user roles and checking them.

## Question 1

How to save the user role so that connect-roles can access it?

## Question 2

Why does console.log return a function instead of true or false?

### I setup passport & connect-roles in my server.coffee

```
...
passport = require('passport')
require('./backend/config/passport')(passport) #pass passport for configuration
ConnectRoles = require('connect-roles')

appUser = new ConnectRoles(
  failureHandler: (req, res, action) ->
    # optional function to customise code that runs when
    # appUser fails authorisation
    accept = req.headers.accept or ''
    res.status 403
    if ~accept.indexOf('html')
      res.render 'access-denied', action: action
    else
      res.send 'Access Denied - You don\'t have permission to: ' + action
    return
  userProperty: 'appUser'
)

...

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session()) # persistent login sessions
app.use(appUser.middleware())

...

appUser.use 'superAdmin', (req) ->
  if req.appUser.role == 'superAdmin'
    return true
  return

...
require('./backend/routes.js')(app, passport, appUser, db, environment)
```

### When the user logs in it should attach the user permission level to the session

```
  passport.use 'local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
    passwordField: 'password'
    passReqToCallback: true
  }, (req, email, password, done) ->
    UserModel.findOne { 'email': email, 'active': true }, (err, user) ->
      if err
        return done(err)
      if !user
        console.log 'Emailadresse unbekannt'
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Emailadresse unbekannt'})
      if !user.validPassword(password)
        console.log 'Passwort nicht korrekt'
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Passwort nicht korrekt'})

      console.log "user with id: #{user._id} and permissionLevel: #{user.permissionLevel} has logged in"
      req.appUser = {} if !req.appUser?
      switch user.permissionLevel
        when 'superAmdin'
          req.appUser.role = 'superAmdin'
        when 'national'
          req.appUser.role = 'national'
        when 'nationalField'
          req.appUser.role = 'nationalField'
        when 'institute'
          req.appUser.role = 'institute'
        when 'employee'
          req.appUser.role = 'employee'
        when 'patient'
          req.appUser.role = 'patient'
      done null, user
    return
```

### Checking the user level in the routes

```
#==================================================== INSTITUTE ====================================================
  app.post('/createInstitute', cleanBody, (req, res) ->
    console.log "permission"
    console.log appUser.is('superAdmin')
    if appUser.is('superAdmin')
      instituteService.createInstitute(db, req.body.institute, (err, instituteId) ->
        if (err)
          return res.json({ err: err })
        return res.json(instituteId: instituteId)
      )
    else return res.json({ err: "keine ausreichende Berechtigung" })
  )
```

### The log show not true or false on user.is

```
permission
{ [Function] here: [Function] }
```

Answer (score 2):

## Code Change User Object

I figured out that defining the user identifier in connect.roles alone does not work. Passport uses an user object which is retrieved with `req.user`. The ID is saved in the session and passport retrieves the full user object with the help of the id on each route. To make it easier I renamed all my users in my application to a different name and use now `user` instead of `appUser` for my authorization.

## 2 Checking the role

Instead of trying to read out my permissions (`permissionLevel`, which is saved in my user database) I do instead check the permissionLevel directly which is in my user model.

In the route you have to use `req.user.is` instead of `user.is`:

```
 appUser.use 'superAdmin', (req) ->
  if req.user.permissionLevel == 'superAdmin'
    return true
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with this middleware, but I figured I'd show how to do this using the [express-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express) library as well, as it's probably the closest library with similar functionality.

Here's how you'd initialize the library, and require admins to access a route.

```
var express = require('express');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

var app = express();

app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  apiKeyId: 'xxx',
  apiKeySecret: 'yyy',
  application: 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/xxx'
}));

app.get('/secret', stormpath.groupsRequired(['admins']), function(req, res) {
  res.json({ status: 'you are an admin!' });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

TO elaborate further, you can use Stormpath to create Groups as well. You can do it pragmatically or via their UI. Here's a code sample:

```
var adminsGroup;
app.get('stormpathApplication').createGroup({ name: 'admins' }, function(err, group) {
  adminsGroup = group;
});
```

Then, later on in your route code, you can add a user to this group by saying something like:

```
app.get('/createAdmin', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
  req.user.addGroup(adminsGroup);  // this adds the current user to the admins group
});
```

Comment: if `groupsRequired` checks if you are an admin where do you set that the user is an admin?

Comment: You can create groups in the UI, or pragmatically by saying: `req.app.get('stormpathApplication').createGroup({ name: 'admins' }, function(err, group) {

Comment: Err -- just updated the answer with more details about your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue about setting user roles, but I figured it out.

Basically since connect-roles is a middleware, every strategy has access to the `req` object, which may have a `user` property set by your authentication library with data from your database (or any other place where you store user data).

Now, since this object gets properties and values from the database you can add a role property to your user, and that gets attached to the `req` object. This way, now you have a property `req.user.role` that you can use inside your strategy.